# Save Scheduled Task (PYTHON Script NOT Batch file) Console Output to a file

Tags: python, windows, taskscheduler

I have found several solutions to save a batch file run from task scheduler to a txt file but the same technique of appending a > file.txt doesn't work for a python script which i am triggering through the task scheduler.  Also tried >> file.txt

How to i save a python script console output to a txt file which is executed from the task scheduler?

This is the command that i am executing from the task scheduler, which is running fine except that it doest save the console output to the txt file.

Program Script - C:\Python27\python.exe

C:\Dropbox\Nightly_SSIM.py > C:\LAF\6.7\Nightly_Debug.txt

Answer (score 1):

If you use the command line just like this in task scheduler:

```
C:\Dropbox\Nightly_SSIM.py > C:\LAF\6.7\Nightly_Debug.txt
```

then it just runs as a python process, where '>' re-direction is not recognized. I would try using the following in task scheduler:

```
cmd.exe /c C:\Dropbox\Nightly_SSIM.py > C:\LAF\6.7\Nightly_Debug.txt
```

Comment: This doesn't work as the program i am executing with is C:\Python27\python.exe , so when i put cmd.exe in the front the python script doesn't execute.

Comment: Oh... can you put cmd.exe as the program instead, and put "C:\Python27\python.exe C:\Dropbox\Nightly_SSIM.py > C:\LAF\6.7\Nightly_Debug.txt" as the arguments?

Comment: In general the paths may need to be quoted, in which case the entire command should also be quoted. For example: `/c ""C:\Python27\python.exe" "C:\Dropbox\Nightly_SSIM.py" > "C:\LAF\6.7\Nightly_Debug.txt""`. Of course, the shell isn't strictly required for this. You can add a command-line option to the Python script to support redirecting `sys.stdout` or even the low-level C stdout (i.e. file descriptor 1).